# Is possible upload image with facebook sdk with description on android?

Tags: android, facebook, image, share

I want to only simple upload photo with facebook sdk. I have installed native app, but did not make submission for publish_actions. Is possible upload image without this permission with my description or create publish dialog with default description?

i could not find class with this ability

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If the app is intended to publish only on your account or any developer, tester account you added in app page in Facebook developer then you don't need to review your permission and you can use it right away.

Or you can invoke the share dialog which doesn't require the user to be logged in at all.

Ref: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share

Comment: In my Users share their photo on facebook, but i want to set default description. SharedDialog don't allow set description.

Comment: Then you need to review your permission.